# Stub function with return function with sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, sinon, stub

I want to make unit testing and cover my code, this is my code, how can cover the createClient with sinon ?

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function(options) {
    if (options.error) {
      if (options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        return new Error('The server refused the connection');
      }
      if (options.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
        return new Error('The server reset the connection');
      }
      if (options.error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
        return new Error('The server timeouted the connection');
      }
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
      return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to test the function assigned to `retry_strategy` would be to move it outside the `redis.createClient` call and export it:

```
export const retryStrategy = function (options) {
  if (options.error) {
    if (options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
      return new Error('The server refused the connection');
    }
    if (options.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
      return new Error('The server reset the connection');
    }
    if (options.error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
      return new Error('The server timeouted the connection');
    }
  }
  if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
    return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
  }
  if (options.attempt > 10) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
}

const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: retryStrategy
  ...
```

Then you can import it and test it directly:

```
import { retryStrategy } from './your-module';

test('retryStrategy', () => {
  expect(retryStrategy({ attempt: 5 })).toBe(500);  // SUCCESS
  ...
})
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `sinon` to mock `redis.createClient`, then get the object it was called with to get access to the function.  It takes more code, let me know if you want me to update my answer with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that you can do is using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to mock `redis.createClient` to return the `opt` so we can access `retry_strategy`. In the test, we call `retry_strategy` and pass its `options`

```
// test.js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const src = proxyquire('./your-source-file', { 'redis': { createClient(opt) { 
  return opt 
}}});
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('testing redis ', function() {
  it('refuses connection', function() {
    const options = {
      error: {
        code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
      }
    }

    expect(src.retry_strategy(options).message).to.equal('The server refused the connection');            
  });
});
```

Here is the source file that I used for testing

```
// source.js
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function(options) {
    if (options.error) {
      if (options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        return new Error('The server refused the connection');
      }
      if (options.error.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
        return new Error('The server reset the connection');
      }
      if (options.error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
        return new Error('The server timeouted the connection');
      }
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
      return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  }
});

module.exports = client;
```